# How to get data in xml file to array in Angular js 4

Tags: arrays, xml, angular, typescript

How to get data in xml file to array in angularjs 4

I have an example in xml below

```
<data>
<element>ESA</element>
<element>XCAVS</element>
<element>TQSZ</element>
<element>HGDQZ</element>
<element>OMGDS</element>
</data>
```

And I want to get data in tag element such as ESA,XCAVS,TQSZ to array in angularjs4.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal javascript for parsing the above xml like the given code below

```
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text1 = "<data>"
+ "<element>ESA</element>" +
  "<element>XCAVS</element>" +
  "<element>TQSZ</element>" +
  "<element>HGDQZ</element>" +
  "<element>OMGDS</element>" +
  "</data>";
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text1,"text/xml");

var sizex = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("element");

var arr = [];
for (i = 0 ; i < sizex.length ; i++) {
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("element")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
arr.push(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("element")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These is not a real code solution but it could help : 
https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

It is a super library that transform your xml to json. After that, it will be easier to play with your data.